# How to set timeout for get_meta_tags() & get_headers()

Tags: php, timeout, get-headers

I've been using the get_meta_tags() & get_headers() PHP functions, and need to set a timeout value in case the website is slow or unresponsive.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to influence this (as it's via URL wrappers) with the `default_socket_timeout` ini setting.

Try either setting it in the `php.ini` file or by doing something like

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
```

to set a 10 sec timeout (the default value is 60)

Comment: thanks a lot for that tip, just tested it, and it works!  I am just worried now that it might affect other PHP functions.  Is there any way to just set the timeout on those 2 functions, or maybe monitor how long they are running for, then abort them after a number of seconds?

Comment: Also helpful: [php get_headers exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518645/php-get-headers-exception-handling)

Answer (score 7):

The `get_headers` and `get_meta_tags` function use the default [HTTP Stream Wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) underneath. You can either [change the ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) as [shown elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6050464/208809) or [modify the behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php) of that wrapper and set a specific timeout:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 5
        )
    )
);
```

Note that changing the default HTTP Stream Context will apply to all functions using it. If you want to restore the timeout to the original default settings, do:

```
$originalDefaults = stream_context_set_default( … );
$meta = get_meta_tags( … );
stream_context_set_default($originalDefaults);
```

On a sidenote, if you call any functions using an HTTP Stream Wrapper, PHP will also automatically populate the [variable `$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) in the current scope, so you don't have to call `get_headers` in addition, e.g.

```
$originalDefaults = stream_context_set_default( … );
$meta = get_meta_tags( … );
stream_context_set_default($originalDefaults);
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Comment: This is not working for me as posted here. `stream_context_set_default` returns `ressource` type and takes `array` (I get a error) so am I supposed to cast `ressource` to array to put it back in?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this as posted by @Gordon just with get_headers but `stream_context_set_default` returns `ressource` and not a array so I am not sure how I am supposed to feed that back into the same function. It expect a array.

```php
$originalDefaults = stream_context_set_default( … );
$meta = get_meta_tags( … );
stream_context_set_default($originalDefaults);
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

In php 7.1 there was a 3rd parameter added to `get_headers`. So I came up with this. When on a not outdated PHP version the option is added to the get headers call only, otherwise the defaults will stick for the rest of the script execution until someone explains to me how to do it on older php versions.

```php
function ngt_headers( $url ) {

    $opts['http']['timeout'] = 2;

    if ( version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.1.0', '>=') ) {
        $context = stream_context_create( $opts );
        return @get_headers( $url, 0, $context ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors.Discouraged
    } else {
        stream_context_set_default( $opts );
        return @get_headers( $url ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors.Discouraged
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@redanimalwar, how about getting the default options and setting it back for to the context, something like this:

```
    $opts['http']['timeout'] = 2;

    $headers = null;
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.1.0', '>=')) {
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $headers =  @get_headers($url, 0, $context);
    } else {
        $defaultOptions = stream_context_get_options(stream_context_get_default());
        stream_context_set_default($opts);
        $headers = @get_headers($url);
        stream_context_set_default($defaultOptions);
    }

    return $headers;
```