# How can I retrieve information from the <meta> tag and display it on a webpage?

Tags: html, meta-tags

For example, if I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Question">
    <meta name="keywords" content="StackExchange, Webmasters">
    <meta name="author" content="Jon Doe">
</head>
```

I need the following to be displayed somewhere on the webpage:

- **Description**: Question
- **Keywords**: StackExchange, Webmasters
- **Author**: Jon Doe

How could I achieve this?

Comment: That's not really what meta tags are for. What exactly are you trying to do here? And why not just output the relevant information again, in the appropriate spot in the markup? (Using whatever is managing your site, eg. WordPress.)

Comment: There are a bunch of languages that does this functionality. You should specify using what language you need that to be done in the very first place. Using normal javascript, jQuery you can achieve this. Using server side languages like jsp, php also you can achieve the same. Refine your question is my suggestion here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you would first grab the Meta information with `get_meta_tags()` as an array and echo the different meta tags to wherever you want them to be displayed on your page.

For example:

```
$metastealer = get_meta_tags('http://yourdomain.com');
echo $metastealer['description'];
echo $metastealer['keywords'];
echo $metastealer['author'];
```

More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php), [here](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.get-meta-tags.htm) and if something doesn't quite work right probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050393/how-to-set-timeout-for-get-meta-tags-get-headers).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want, but you could of course display the attribute values of the actual `meta` elements with CSS:

```
head, meta {display:block;}
meta[name="description"]::after {content:"Description: " attr(content);}
```

Only advisable if you need a simple/quick way to display it for your own site owner’s need. Don’t use this method if you want the content to be accessible to your visitors. In that case you should repeat the content and mark it up accordingly.