# php_header function kill if it is stuck hang

Tags: php, timeout

When I try to check some URLs my host couldn't reach target server because of my server connection. Once couldn't reach, It didn't return anything PHP hang just stuck. I would like to add KILL command some where in php file to be able to kill connection if it is stuck. Is there anyway to kill connection after certain time? or any if or any other command to resolve this issue? I want to add this command before run header command `timeout -s KILL 10`.

My code is:

```
<?php

function UR_exists($url){
    $headers=get_headers($url);
    return stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}

if(UR_exists("https://www.uni-hohenheim.de/fileadmin/einrichtungen/apo/Hauptseminar_Agraroekonomie_12/Simeon_Ehui_World_Bank.pptx"))
    echo "file exists";
else
    echo "file does not exist";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Likely better to just set a timeout, rather than trying to set an alarm + kill. Setting a timeout will be must easier to work with.

[Setting get_headers() timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050393/how-to-set-timeout-for-get-meta-tags-get-headers) provides good detail about how to do this.

Comment: I already tried this solution I have nginx and php-fpm and it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me: `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$original_default_context = stream_context_set_default(["http" => ["timeout" => 10]]);
$headers = get_headers($url);
stream_context_set_default($original_default_context);
```

This will hang for 10 seconds, then kill the connection.

Comment: <?php
function UR_exists($url){

$original_default_context = stream_context_set_default(["http" => ["timeout" => 10]]);
$headers = get_headers($url);
stream_context_set_default($original_default_context);


return stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}
if(UR_exists("https://www.uni-hohenheim.de/fileadmin/einrichtungen/apo/Hauptseminar_Agraroekonomie_12/Simeon_Ehui_World_Bank.pptx"))
echo "file exists";
else
echo "file does not exist";
?>



I used like this and still don't work stuck and waiting for me to kill